# XCode launch screen: Can't see ImageUIView properties on the right panel when I click

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to add an image to my launch screen with XCode, I added an ImageUIView to the launch screen storyboard, now I want to change image property to add one of the images sets i added.

**When I click it shows View properties on the right panel, it should show Image View properties instead?**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0KmP.png

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to go to ```Content Mode``` tab

Comment: can you post a screenshot? I can't find it, I'm new to macs

Comment: Is the tab with the "pin" icon

Comment: It should be the fifth tab